# JavaScript Horizontal Slider

Tags: javascript, html, dom, scroll

I'm attempting to write a horizontal slider without JQuery for a project I'm doing for my own practice/enjoyment.

Here is the relevant code:

```
function moveit() {
    "use strict";
    document.getElementById("position").style.left = window.event.clientX + "px";
}

window.onload = function () {
    "use strict";
    findtime();
    document.getElementById("scrollbar").style.width = document.getElementById("thevideo").offsetWidth + "px";
    var mousemove;
    document.getElementById("scrollbar").onclick = function () {
            mousemove = window.setInterval("moveit()", 1000);
    };
    document.getElementById("scrollbar").mouseup = function () {
            window.clearInterval(mousemove);
    };
};
```

Needless to say I'm having issues with it. It constantly generates the error on Chrome, Firefox, etc.:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined
```

Now if I run the following code it works, however (but is not useful for following mouse position):

```
document.getElementById("position").style.left = 12 + "px";
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
            <div>
                    <video id="thevideo">
                            <source src="movie.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
                    </video>
            </div>
            <div>
                    <span id="currenttime" contenteditable="true">0:00</span> / <span id="totaltime"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="scrollbar">
                    <div id="position" draggable="true"></div>
            </div>
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I made a while back, maybe you can adjust it to your program.

```
var scrollTimer;

function Timer(callback, delay) {
    var timerId, start, remaining = delay;
    this.pause = function() {
        window.clearTimeout(timerId);
        remaining -= new Date() - start;
    };
    this.resume = function() {
        start = new Date();
        timerId = window.setTimeout(callback, remaining);
    };
    this.resume();
}

function scroll(down) {
  var scrollframe = document.getElementById("contentframe");
  var curY = document.all?
    scrollframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollTop
  : scrollframe.contentWindow.window.pageYOffset;
  var delta = 5;
  var newY = down? curY+delta : curY-delta;
  scrollframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(0,newY);
}

function autoscroll(down) {
  scroll(down);
  scrollTimer = new Timer(function() {
    autoscroll(down);
  }, 20);
}

function stopscroll() {
  scrollTimer.pause();
}
```

The function scroll(boolean down) causes a single `delta` incremental upward or downward scroll to the iframe `contentframe`. The timer is used to repeat that action, and here is how you would use it:

```
<a href=#>
<img src="scroller/arrowTop.png" title="Scroll Up"
    onMouseOver="autoscroll(false);" onMouseOut="stopscroll();"/>
</a>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note: This is a vertical scroller. You would have to alter it so that it changes `window.pageXOffset` and `body.scrollLeft` instead of `window.pageYOffset` and `body.scrollTop` to make it work in the horizontal plane. Not forgetting `contentWindow.scrollTo(newX,0)`

Comment: Umm, I'm not sure I understand this code:  document.all?
    scrollframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollTop
  : scrollframe.contentWindow.window.pageYOffset;. Why the question mark and why the colon?

Comment: @user798080 It is a short-hand conditional statement, its the same as writing this: `var curY; if (document.all) curY=scrollframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollTop; else curY=scrollframe.contentWindow.windiw.pageYOffset;`. The way you should read `x=(condition)?a:b;` is `assign x to (if condition is true, return A, else return B)`

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there - there's no `window.event` object in standard JS. So use the [DOM Event Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event#DOM_Event_interface):

```
function moveit(e) {
    "use strict";
    document.getElementById("position").style.left = e.clientX + "px";
}

window.onload = function (e) {
    "use strict";
    findtime();
    document.getElementById("scrollbar").style.width = document.getElementById("thevideo").offsetWidth + "px";
    var mousemove;
    document.getElementById("scrollbar").onclick = function () {
            mousemove = window.setInterval(moveit, 1000);
    };
    document.getElementById("scrollbar").mouseup = function () {
            window.clearInterval(mousemove);
    };
};
```